# Actionbar still reacts to input when overlayed by CAB

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, cab, contextual-action-bar

I'm using the Toolbar from android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar and sometimes it gets overlayed from a Contextual ActionBar (CAB). So far it's working as expected.
But the Toolbar still reacts to touch-input, when its overlayed.

That can't be the wanted behaviour.
Am i missing something really trivial?

Thanks and best regards.